# Can I live capture midi with rtmidi while using Ableton?

Tags: python, midi, ableton-live, mido, pyportmidi

I'm creating a pygame that renders midi notes on a grid and I'd like to be able to use the same midi input through Ableton at the same time.

Right now I'm using this to capture:

```
inport = mido.open_input(synth_name)
msg = inport.receive()
```

Is there a way to do this while playing through Ableton?

Answer (score 0):

You can only open a MIDI port with one application at a time, but an option would be to route your MIDI singal through Ableton.

If you're on Windows, the free [loopMIDI](https://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/loopmidi.html) software allows you to create a virtual MIDI loopback port.

Route the original signal into Ableton, do whatever synth stuff you like, and send it to your virtual MIDI input port. Your pygame can then open the virtual MIDI output port.

All this works with virtually no extra latency.